# Angular 14: Angular animation causes form submission to occur when deleting item from FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-animations

I started creating animations for my app and I noticed when I delete an element from a `FormArray` it triggers a form submission.  I made custom form controls using `ControlValueAccessor` and pass some of my `FormGroup`s through `@Input`s.  The animation I'm using looks like this

```
export const smallItem = trigger('smallItem',[
  transition('void => *', [
    animate('80ms', keyframes([
      style({
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'translateY(-80px) scale(0.7)',
        zIndex: 5,
        offset: 0
      }),
      style({
        transform: 'translateY(-20px) scale(0.7)',
        opacity: 1,
        offset: 0.6
      }),
      style({
        transform: 'translateY(0) scale(0.7)',
        offset: 0.9
      }),
      style({
        transform: 'scale(1.3)',
        zIndex: 7,
        offset: 0.95
      }),
      style({
        transform: 'scale(1)',
        zIndex: 6,
        offset: 1
      })
    ]))
  ]),
  transition('* => void', [
    animate('300ms', keyframes([
      style({
        opacity: 1,
        transform: 'translateY(0) scale(1)',
        zIndex: 6,
        offset: 0
      }),
      style({
        transform: 'translateY(0) scale(0.7)',
        zIndex: 5,
        offset: 0.3
      }),
      style({
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'translateY(-80px) scale(0.7)',
        offset: 1
      })
    ]))
  ])
])
```

I import it into my component and apply it to an `*ngFor` element like this

```
<section class="expressionControlShell" formArrayName="expressions">

  <media-expression-input *ngFor="let a of ExpressionList.controls; let i = index"
    [MediaExpressionForm]="a"
    [GroupId]="i"
    [ShowDelete]="i === 0 ? false : true"
    (DeleteItem)="removeMediaExpression($any($event))"
    @smallItem
  ></media-expression-input>

</section>
```

I've also tried using `[@smallItem]` as well which still works and also submits the form.  When I remove the animation all together I can delete elements without triggering a submission.  I don't know what to look into or tinker with to try resolving this issue and haven't been able to find any similar issues online but to see what I mean [open this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g9pacu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.module.ts,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-selector-input%2Fmedia-selector-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fviewbox-input%2Fviewbox-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-query-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-query-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fviewbox-input%2Fviewbox-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fdemo.svg,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-component%2Fsvg.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-builder.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-component%2Fsvg.component.svg,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-component%2Fsvg.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-builder.component.svg,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-builder.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-selector-input%2Fmedia-selector-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-query-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fanimations.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-expression-input%2Fmedia-expression-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.ts&file=src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fviewbox-input%2Fviewbox-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.html%3AL14-L14,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input-component.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-query-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Finterfaces.ts) and follow these steps.

***1. Open the inspector and select the console tab.***

***2. Scroll down and click on `add media query` button.***

***3. In the new media query form click on the `add expression` button.***

***4. When the new expression pops up click the `delete` button.***

Inside the console you will see an object appear which I only `console.log()` in the function I made for processing the form.  On the screen beneath the media queries you'll also see a window pop up showing a JSON object which is only visible after the form is submitted.  Does anybody know what might make this occur and how to stop it?

Comment: what does your TS and HTML look like? It might be something as basic as your button input type being set to submit instead of just button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue lies in that `<button>` by default has a type of 'submit', playing with your stackblitz and setting the type to be 'button' prevents the submission.

Edit so your HTML goes from:

```
<article class="buttonShell">
    <button class="deleteButton" *ngIf="ShowDelete" (click)="removeGroup()">delete</button>
  </article>
```

To:

```
<article class="buttonShell">
    <button type="button" class="deleteButton" *ngIf="ShowDelete" (click)="removeGroup()">delete</button>
  </article>
```

Inside of your MediaExpressionInput component

Comment: THAT WORKS!!!  I thought I had added `type="button"` to that button, I normally do lol. thanks :).